# Setting React state in OnMouseDown event causing no text selection

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I've this code in a classic React class:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    isMouseHolding: false
  }

  this.handleOnMouseDown = this.handleOnMouseDown.bind(this);
  this.handleOnMouseUp = this.handleOnMouseUp.bind(this);
}

handleOnMouseDown(event) {
  this.setState({
    isMouseHolding: true
  });
}

handleOnMouseUp() {
  this.setState({
    isMouseHolding: false
  });
}

<div onMouseDown={this.handleOnMouseDown} onMouseUp={this.handleOnMouseUp}>
    ...
</div>
```

The state is setting normally but now if I select a text it is not highlighted.

How can we propagate the event so that it behave normally but with changing the state?

**EDIT:**

What I need is just to keep select the text (such as every web-page when you hold the mouse on a text) but also change state.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking.  Are you trying to drag and drop the `div` or highlight the text inside to copy/paste?

Comment: Somewhere in your JSX you would have to deal with the changed state, e.g ...className={this.state.isMouseHolding ? "holdingCssClass" : "defaultCssClass"} ... which is not shown. What do you refer to with "propagate the event ..."?

Comment: Created a simple ReactJS app. Looks like there is no problem with selecting text. https://codepen.io/chumakoff/pen/LYYGPar
  Do you have any idea what causes the selection loss? Maybe the text you are selecting is changing?

Comment: I need to keep select the text (such as every web-page when you hold the mouse on a text) but also change state.